# Force equal height of the image as the parallel text div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible in CSS to have the equal height of the image as the parallel div that contains the textual data. I have applied both div's the CSS properties  `display: table-cell;`.
Here is the desired results which I am going to achieve. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using flexbox instead of your table-cell approach:

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
}
.ImgContainer, .TextContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

.ImgContainer {
  background: orange;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.TextContainer {
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="ImgContainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x75" />
  </div>
  <div class="TextContainer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>


</div>
```

**Edit:** I see you've updated your question and want to stretch the image. This makes it a bit more difficult. Usually, I use the `background-image` css properties because it lets me use the excellent `background-size: cover`. Semantically and in terms of accessibility, it's a bit worse though...

Try it out by removing the `<img>` and change the css for `.ImgContainer`:

```
.ImgContainer {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x75);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Absolutely position the image, hide the overflow

Whether you use `flex` or `table` for your layout, the trick is to use `position: absolute` on your `img` in conjunction with `height: 100%` and, on your image container, `overflow: hidden`.

You may center the image by using `translate(-50%, -50%)` in conjunction with `top: 50%; bottom: 50%`.

**Example w/ flex-box:**

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.content .image,
.content .text {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content .image {
  display: flex;
  /* Required to keep `img` inside this container */
  position: relative;
  /* Hides any part of image that overflows the container */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content .image img {
  /* Taken out of the flow so `img` does not affect height of container */
  position: absolute;
  /* Put top left corner of `img` at center of container */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Translate top left corner position of `img` by -50% of the height/width of the container, which absolutely centers the `img`. */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Force `img` to always be height of container, while width may be wider or narrower according to aspect ratio. */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis rem eos ducimus laboriosam voluptatibus, dolore culpa. Quis magnam optio nobis, sapiente sequi dicta magni perspiciatis minus sit deleniti officia perferendis in quos facere doloribus ratione molestiae soluta ipsa consectetur, labore! Quibusdam totam saepe, minima optio, necessitatibus distinctio ipsum minus maxime veritatis dolorem maiores quo iusto ullam temporibus qui nobis repellat aperiam officiis ea, illo quod labore. Minima quos placeat unde.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x200">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis rem eos ducimus laboriosam voluptatibus, dolore culpa. Minima quos placeat unde.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example w/ table:**

```css
.content {
  display: table;
}
.content .image,
.content .text {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content .image {
  /* Required to keep `img` inside this container */
  position: relative;
  /* Hides any part of image that overflows the container */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content .image img {
  /* Taken out of the flow so `img` does not affect height of container */
  position: absolute;
  /* Put top left corner of `img` at center of container */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Translate top left corner position of `img` by -50% of the height/width of the container, which absolutely centers the `img`. */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Force `img` to always be height of container, while width may be wider or narrower according to aspect ratio. */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis rem eos ducimus laboriosam voluptatibus, dolore culpa. Quis magnam optio nobis, sapiente sequi dicta magni perspiciatis minus sit deleniti officia perferendis in quos facere doloribus ratione molestiae soluta ipsa consectetur, labore! Quibusdam totam saepe, minima optio, necessitatibus distinctio ipsum minus maxime veritatis dolorem maiores quo iusto ullam temporibus qui nobis repellat aperiam officiis ea, illo quod labore. Minima quos placeat unde.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x200">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis rem eos ducimus laboriosam voluptatibus, dolore culpa. Minima quos placeat unde.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do this by `display:table` and and `table-cell` this code works on old browsers too

```css
.content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.image,.text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis rem eos ducimus laboriosam voluptatibus, dolore culpa. Quis magnam optio nobis, sapiente sequi dicta magni perspiciatis minus sit deleniti officia perferendis in quos facere doloribus
    ratione molestiae soluta ipsa consectetur, labore! Quibusdam totam saepe, minima optio, necessitatibus distinctio ipsum minus maxime veritatis dolorem maiores quo iusto ullam temporibus qui nobis repellat aperiam officiis ea, illo quod labore. Minima
    quos placeat unde.</div>
</div>
```